# Pass value of selected country (dropdown) in session and then reload current page (Rails 4)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app, I'm trying to ask the user in the footer which country he'd like to see (France/United States/Germany...) and then store this in session and reload the page he's currently on.

Note that: I just want the current page to reload but I don't want to add a params in the URLs of my app(ie I don't want example.com/browser_country=France). I want them to stay as they are (example.com).

How can I do that?

This is my code below but it's not working (i'm a Rails newbie):

```
<footer class="footer">

    <small>
        MySuper Website <br/>
        <select name= "browser_country", :onchange => "location.href = '#{current_path}'"  >
           <option value="">Select Country</option>
              <option value="1">France</option>
              <option value="2">United States</option>
        </select>

    </small>
```

Here if the controller that loads the page (homepage)on  /app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home        
  end

  def set_country_into_session
    session[:country] = :browser_country # i'm putting in session the country selected in the dropdown
  end       

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add an ajax call to this process.

```
# your js file
$(function() {
    $('select[name="browser_country"]').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'static_pages/set_country_into_session',
            data: 'browser_country=' + this.value,
            success: function() {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});

# static_pages_controller.rb
def set_country_into_session
  session[:country] = params[:browser_country]

  render text => :ok
end
```